# error printing a serialized array ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

when I try to print a serialized array I get this error "Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String"

Here is where I attempt to print array

```
<% unless post.raffle_id.nil? %>
        Buyers:<% post.raffle_id.each do |t| %>
            <%= t %> 
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is where array is defined in post model

```
serialize :raffle_id, Array
```

the type on raffle_id in the data base schema is of type text.

Comment: Can you show the information present on `raffle_id` attribute ? It must looks like `--- [ a, b, c ]` for array.

Comment: what most probably happened is that the value of `raffle_id` was set before adding the code to serialize it to an Array.

Comment: how do I fix this jvnill?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #post.rb 
 class  Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
   serialize :raffle_id, Array 
 end
```

In your console verify the Post:

```
Post.inspect 
"Post(id: integer .... , raffle_id: text)" 

a = Post.new(raffle_id: [1,2,3])
a.save 
Now try to Print variable a value: 
  $ a.raffle_id
 => [1,2,3]
```

Verify above in your console, this is expected to work. :)

Comment: when I typed inspect this is what appeared "Post (call 'Post.connection' to establish a connection)" everything else worked though

Comment: That's fine. initially we need to establish connection. You can query for all the records or do just a count, that'll internally establish the connection for you. :)